# Calculated rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column called metrics that have different possible metrics as:

```
Metric  Value
--------------
A       100
B       200
C       300
```

I want to derive another table from this base table that may have rows like:

```
Metric  Value
--------------
A       100
B       200
C       300
C/A     3
B/A     2
```

Basically keeping original rows as is + adding some new rows based on existing value's combinations.

One way I could think of doing this is:
1. Pivot the data
2. Put it in some temp table or CTE
3. Select all existing metric columns + New calculated columns I need
4. unpivot the output of the last step

Is there a better way to achieve this with SQL? Or perhaps any other possible way?
Also, redshift doesn't support Pivot function, is there a workaround for that in addition to using Case Statements?

Comment: Are you using Amazon Redshift, MS SQL Server, or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Have you thought about using a Procedure?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Put the additional rows into a second table, create a view for the union of both tables.

Comment: @jmelesky - I work with both Redshift PostgreSQL and SQL Server, so I am interested to find solutions applicable to both or the either one.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the table with itself and apply the operation on the pairs of metrics you like. And `UNION ALL` the table as it is to include the original metrics.

One possibility for your example would be (assuming Postgres):

```
SELECT metric,
       value
       FROM metrics
UNION ALL
SELECT concat(m1.metric, '/', m2.metric),
       m1.value / m2.value
       FROM metrics m1
            CROSS JOIN metrics m2
       WHERE (m1.metric,
              m2.metric) IN (('C',
                              'A'),
                             ('B',
                              'A'));
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c07a2/4)

Of course this could be extended to ternary, ... operations by adding another join and several different operations by adding other queries and `UNION`ing them.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
case when x1.metric = x2.metric 
    then x1.metric 
else x1.metric || ' / ' || x2.metric end,
case when x1.metric = x2.metric 
    then x1.value 
else x1.value / x2.value end

from mytable x1
join mytable x2
  on x1.metric = x2.metric or x2.metric = 'A'
```

This is one way to do it, and its using purely standard sql. Note however, that different RDMBS software have different levels of standards-conformance, and may not support some of the features used here. Specifically, string concatenation operator `||` isn't implemented in all databases. Some databases use the function `concat` or `+` instead.